# max function not returning right ouput

Tags: python, max

(I am pretty new to python)
Hey guys, so I was trying to code a simple python program which finds the HCF of two numbers, but I am getting an error when the two numbers are co-prime and the actual HCF is not showing for the two numbers
(Ex: The HCF for 12 and 24 should be 12 but python is showing 4

Here is the code, can any of you guys help me?

```py
factors = []
print("Enter first number")
num1 = int(input())
print("Enter second number")
num2 = int(input())
if num1 < num2:
    lesser = num1
else:
    lesser = num2
for i in range(2, lesser + 2):
    if num1 % i == 0 and num2 % i == 0:
        factors.append(i)
if not factors:
    print(num1, "and", num2, "are co-prime numbers, so they don't have any common factors")
str_factors = ', '.join(map(str, factors))
hcf = max(str_factors)
print(hcf)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are turning `factors` into a comma separated string and using `max` on the string. It's giving you the max of the string lexicographically. You need to use `max` on the `factors` variable.

Say for a string `'2, 12, 42, 13'` `max` will return `'4'` because it loops through all characters in a string

Fix this line and it should produce you expected output

```
hcf = max(factors)
```